# Trocar on click por checkox checked

Tags: javascript, ajax, checkbox

Olá, tenho uma função que funciona perfeitamente no javascript uso um ajax ao clicar no botão pra enviar meus dados, só que agora ao inves de clicar no botão, quero trocar para quando a pessoa marcar o checkbox, ele deveria executar a função da mesma forma, só que não funciona de jeito nenhum. Se puderem me ajudar agradeço. Tentei fazer assim:

```
var addProduto = function(){

      //termos é o nome do meu checkbox
      if (document.getElementById('termos').checked) {

           var id_produto = $(this).attr('data-id');

            $.ajax({
               type: 'post',
               url: url_painel +'carrinho/add',
               data: {id:id_produto},
               dataType: "JSON"
            }).then(function(res){

               if (res.erro == 0) {

                 alert ('produto adicionado com sucesso');

               } else{

                 alert(res.msg);

               }

            }, function(){
                alert('Erro');
            });             
            } else{
                alert('Você precisa aceitar os termos e uso de serviços antes de continuar');
            }


    }
```

Ela funciona com :

```
$('.btn-add-produto-carrinho').on('click', function(){
```

Mas com checkbox não. Se puderem me ajudar agradeço.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bom Dia!!

O Javascript fica escutando eventos, ou seja, seu checkbox não está funcionando pq quando você inicia sua página, ele já inicializa esse JS, provavelmente aparecendo a mensagem da condição Else.

Você pode fazer como o Francisco segeriu, adicionando o evento onclick na sua tag input:checkbox, ou usando o **addEventListener**, como no exemplo abaixo.

```js
let checkboxTermos = document.querySelector("#termos");

checkboxTermos.addEventListener( 'change', function() {
    if(this.checked) {
        console.log("Executa o código quando a Checkbox estiver ticada")
    } else {
        console.log("Executa quando não estiver ticada")
    }
});
```

```html
<label>Li e concordo com os termpos</label>
<input id="termos" type="checkbox">
```

Comment: mto obrigado pela ajuda, eu fiz assim como demostrou só que ai ele anula meu ajax, cai direto no erro. E no botão ele envia os dados normais, só que com o checkbox ele anula a função de ajax.

Comment: Como assim? Você só chama este evendo quando clicar no checkbox. Já que você está usando Jquery no seu Ajax, pq não utiliza para fazer a função?

$(function() {
    $('#termos').change(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
       
        $.ajax({
            url: "",
            type: 'post',
            success: function(result) {
                
            },
            error: function() {
            }
        });
    });
});

Comment: fiz uma mudança no ajax e consegui com sua ajuda. Vlw amigo.

Answer (score 3):

Olá, você poderia adicionar o evento de clique ao campo `checkbox` para disparar a função com o ajax.

Exemplo:

```js
const checkboxTermos = document.querySelector("#termos");
checkboxTermos.onclick = function() {
  //verifica se o campo checkbox está marcado
  if (this.checked) {
    console.log("true");
  } else {
    console.log("false");
  }
};
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" id="termos">
  <label for="termos">termos</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Vlw pela ajuda tb amigos.